# WP7 Changing Tile elements using code

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Is it possible to change the tile background image through code. The scenario is "The initial tile image(not the default image, I have created my own image and set it as the Background.png under tile options) is updated with a new tile background image through pushing a Tile notification and when the user opens the app(either activating or launching) I have to change the new tile background image which was updates through push notification to the initial tile image". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 7.0, just have your app call your notification server to send a new tile notification.

In 7.1 you can use [ShellTile.ActiveTiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.activetiles%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to access the tile and update it.

Comment: I need to change the tile image back to the initial one only if the initial tile image has been updated with some other image. How in the app I can check whether the initial image is replaced with some other image

Comment: @saikamesh you can't query the image but you could just always overwrite it with the initial value